# javascript getting a variable from a child to a parent

Tags: javascript, variables, parent-child, buttonclick, message-passing

I shortened my code dramatically but below relays the point pretty efficiently, I'm trying to get the variable "Monitor" to update if the buttons pressed. I can get the variable through to my code if I put all of my code inside of the "button.onclick" function. However, my code won't run until I press the button. I need my code to run and if a button is pressed it updates my code.

```
<form name="form1">
  <span id="buttons">
    <input type="button" name="button1" value="funny1"/>
    <input type="button" name="button2" value="funny2"/>
  </span>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Monitor, buttonsDiv=document.getElementById("buttons");
    Monitor = "funny1"
    for (var i=1; i<=2; i++) {
        var button = document.form1["button" + i];
        button.onclick = function() {
            buttons.Monitor = this.value;
        };

        /*lots of my own code that runs
        inside of my for loop waiting
        to reference monitor for an update*/

</script>
```

Comment: Why are you changing buttons.Monitor instead of Monitor?

Comment: This is actually just my latest attempt at getting this working, I had it set to Monitor and that didn't work either, I've tried windows.opener's var Monitor buttons.Monitor, and several other things, I'm an experienced programmer but I'm new to java, php, and javascript. been pushing myself for a few weeks learning lots of new things and for some reason javascript seems to be the most difficult to wrap my head around.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you have a loop waiting for something. Putting your code in the event handler for the button click is the normal way to do things in Javascript.

Comment: Yeah, JS is a bit different... so what do you want to have in the end? Why are you looping through all the buttons? Are you trying to update the buttons object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully the following code will get you going in the right direction.  Instead of wiring up all the events per button, I think you were trying to get it so each button would then call into a function that would set the value of Monitor.

```
var Monitor = "funny1";

//selecting all elements named button  
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"]');

//For each of the buttons wire up an event listener
for(var i=0, length=buttons.length; i < length;i++)
{
    //create a reference shorthand
    var button = buttons[i];

    //add the event listener for a click
    button.addEventListener('click', function(event)
    {
        //on the event look at the event's target property to find the element that invoked the click
        Monitor = event.target.value;
        console.log(Monitor);  //Output the value of monitor the the console
    });    
}
```

This code first finds all the inputs with type=button. I suggest you perhaps give the inputs a class instead to make the selector clearer, your choice.  Secondly, I loop through the buttons and wire an event up for each one.  The event then sets the value of the Monitor variable.

http://jsfiddle.net/wcf4c/

Comment: I was still having issues at first, something about the for(var i=0, length=button.length; i < length++) didn't work right for me but I managed to get it working thanks to you, thank you.

Comment: my apologies the problem is still there the problem being that if I put my code inside of the listener it doesn't work until I click a button. if it's outside the listener it doesn't get the results from the listener.

Comment: "button.addEventListener('click', function(event)" listens for a click if I put the code that I want to respond to the variable Monitor inside of the click listener then it does not respond to "monitor = "funny"" until I click something. If my code is outside of that click then it gets the variable "Moniter = "funny"" it however does not get the click input results.

Comment: Let me explain what I'm doing a little better, I have a php script that grabs data from a mysql database, my javascript runs that php script and pulls the data from my php script formatted in json and loads it into a graph. these buttons are supposed to allow you to choose what data is pulled and grabbed from mysql. It all works fantastically except for what I was mentioning above. I do have a temporary solution but it's not very elegant. I pasted my code both inside of the click function and outside of it.